# C# Regex expression needed for data import

Tags: regex

Can somebody please tell me the regex expression to extract

"EUR/USD" from any of the following file names:

QR_IB_EURUSD.Quote.csv

QR_Integral_EURUSD.Quote.csv

QR_Currenex_EURUSD.Quote.csv

Need this to work with other currency pairs as well.

I know   \..* will knock off the file name but how do I get the symbol with a backslash in it?

I dont know what language the regex is in but it's C#.Net or Java

![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_(\w+).
```

And then you extract the value of the grouping.

Comment: this gives me QRQuote.csv   Dont know what you mean by then extract value of the grouping I never wrote a regex in my life =x

Comment: oh sorry, well Im not doing it programmatically, I need to input the expression into a software with a GUI. I think it's C# but it could be Java, not sure. Ill check documentation now

Comment: Well in that case I don't think I can help you :)

Comment: Maybe you could try: _[A-Z]+.Q and replacement would be _.Q

Comment: That actually comes close but kinda the reverse. Gives me

QR_Currenex_.Quote.csv

Comment: Sorry don't know what you mean. The expected outcome is the currency pair with a slash  "EUR/USD" i edit OP with expression to remove the file extension. perhaps one can guess what language it's in from this

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
^\w+_\w+_(\w+)\.Quote\.csv$
```

Here's some JavaScript to demonstrate

```
var test1 = [
    "QR_IB_EURUSD.Quote.csv",
    "QR_Integral_EURUSD.Quote.csv",
    "QR_Currenex_EURUSD.Quote.csv",
    "QR_IB_AUDCAD.Quote.csv"
    ];

for(var i=0; i<test1.length; i++)
    test1[i] = test1[i].match(/^\w+_\w+_(\w+)\.Quote\.csv$/i)[1];

alert(test1);
```

Comment: this just gives me a blank (removes the whole string)

Comment: @Vazgen - if you don't share with us, what programming language your using, what application or even the context that you are applying this "regex" then it's impossible to definitively help you.

Comment: application was written in java but the development framework the user is supposed to use is .NET. I strongly believe the regex is in c# but it may be java. I edited the image in the OP to show the removal of the file extension, perhaps one can guess what language it's in from this hint

Answer (score 0):

Try this out , this is in PERL, will detect if the word has EUR or USD

```
my $file_name = "QR_Integral_EURUSD.Quote.csv" #file name
$file_name =~ m/EUR|USD/
```

You could create any currency pair...

```
m/EUR|USD/
m/INR|AED/
```

or add all in one

```
m/EUR|AED|USD|INR/
```

Comment: thanks but this wont work I'm not doing it programmatically and it's def not in Perl (see image in OP)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo QR_Currenex_EURUSD.Quote.csv | \
sed -r 's/(^.*[_])([A-Z]{3})([A-Z]{3})([.].*$)/\2\/\3/'
EUR/USD
```

In this case, the regex is `(^.*[_])([A-Z]{3})([A-Z]{3})([.].*$)` and the replacement is `\2\/\3`.

Comment: You might try doubling the backslashes in front of the digits only.